# Removing markers from the google map Swift 4

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift4, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am developing an iOS app where I need to show the user some locations over the map. For this I am using the google maps. and its really working fine.

**Informations:**   In my app, I have view controller that is divided into two half. The upper area is showing map and the below area is showing UITableView which contains locations that populates from Database.

**What I have done so far:** Now i am populating my list and google map from the saved locations in database. Let suppose I have 30 different locations and I have shown all locations on map by placing each marker on map and also added that marker into the UItable. Each cell contains location name and the delete button to remove the location from the Database

**What I want:**

> Now what I want is that user can tap on delete button in the cell
>   to remove marker. And I really want to remove that marker from the map
>   also in real time.But I have no clue how to do it. Please help

Answer (score 2):

**Check below code**

```
func removeMarkers(mapView: GMSMapView){
    for (index, _) in markers.enumerate() {
        //print("Item \(index): \(element)")
                    self.markers[index].map = nil
    }
}
```

where

```
var markers = [GMSMarker]()
```

markers contains all the marker overlays for the mapView

**OR**

var markers = GMSMarker
markers contains all the marker overlays for the mapView

on click delete

```
self.markers[index].map = nil
```

Comment: var markers = GMSMarker markers contains all the marker overlays for the mapView I did not understand ths?

Comment: please add all GMSMarkers as a list while adding markers to map, and use this array elements for removing element from map

Comment: you can also refer from google official documentation
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker